# Wiring DPDT (ON-OFF-ON) toggle switch to Two-Speed DC motor - Hours spent on interesting study - Still a fail :-)

Tags: dpdt

Can someone show me, completely even, (*cringe*) on what wires go where.

Here's a picture of the 3 parts. BIG DC BATTERY - TWO SPEED MOTOR - DPDT (ON-OFF-ON) SWITCH

[image: CHANGING SPEED WITH DPDT - diagram of parts]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zTo7.jpg

1. When the switch is in the off position, center of course, the motor is off, then in one direction it goes on, low speed, on the other direction is goes to high speed.
2. When manually connecting the wires it works.

TOPLINE: 2-speed motor - not trying to reverse motor just change between two speeds.

1. it's a chunky 20amp stock acting toggle DPDT ON-OFF-ON - I don't care which direction is high speed or low speed. (when thrown full one way, or,  fully the other way)
2. I need (already have) a wire from every marked point on The battery, AND the 2-speed motor. shown in IMGUR link diagram (above) link work i hope.

Just need to figure out the clever bits for getting the DPDT wired up.

3. I have done tons of study and have down-graded my opinion of my confidence/IQ at figuring stuff out, a lot. heh-heh

--> Could anyone make a point-form list or other, as to exactly how I'd wire-up my current DPDT switch?  (BIG-cringe for asking)

Comment: You can use a DPDT switch, of course. But it may not be necessary. It's possible you could consider an SPDT. But let's go with what you have. What's the part number for your DPDT switch? Or failing that, can you use an Ohmmeter and find out which contacts are connected when the switch is NOT in the center position? There isn't an absolutely safe guide to interpreting those six pin positions, though most do fit a pattern I have in mind. Since you don't want to screw up, it's a good idea to spend the time and make absolutely sure.

Comment: If you dont’ use a full-bride with PWM to soft accelerate the switches will burn out with 20x the rated current at full reverse !!

Comment: Bridge ....rated  for >> your max surge current.. Bemf+Vcc)/DCR

Comment: *whatever happens more than fine of course* - Does that include red-hot wires that burn you or an exploding battery that sends you to the emergency room? Follow jonk's advice, and one more strong recommendation, add a fuse in series with the +battery terminal.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 - no, he's not trying to reverse the motor. I thought the same until I read it 3 times.

Comment: Normally to get a professional Engineering type answer, we have to translate “client-ease “ but expect datasheets to be provided and performance expectations and exceptions from client.  Pls add datasheets or exceptionally good photos. On all parts!

Comment: @stexius Okay with limited information, I am guessing you are referring to wiring a 2 speed motor for for a bus (such as Red Dot 73R0602)? 
Schematic shown in page two of [link](https://www.salvex.com/media/document/Heaters.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the connections shown below will do what you want.

[image]

Comment: "PERFECTION, is when there's nothing left to remove". YOUR WIRING PETER -> So beautifully NOT what I would have guessed, based on my "studies" - hehehe 

[Understatement ALERT] THANK YOU EVERYONE THANK YOU PETER